# How to migrate local Django model changes to production?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm attempting to migrate my local changes to my public production site Django site. The problem I am having is my local changes overwrite my production models, when I upload my local changes to production. Is their a way to merge my changes without totally ruining my production models.

Is there a library that I can use that will better help me manage conflicts between the two code bases?

Comment: Why do you have conflicts? You should not touch the code on a production server but only make changes on your dev environment and copy everything across.

Comment: What is your database configuration locally and in production?

Comment: Hello, you should not modify the code on production, specially **migrations** as it may put you in trouble. So instead of running `makemigrations` command on production always commit it from your local machine to avoid conflicts

Comment: Why you cannot just pull first and then push it all to production?

Comment: @DevangPadhiyar when you say commit it from your local machine, can you explain further. Also, should I not be using the makemigrations command once in production?

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko I'm doing something wrong. When I try this I end up completely overwriting my existing models. Should I pull all while and ignoring a certain local file name?